# How to intercept JUnit5 method annotated with @Disabled?

Tags: junit5

I would like to write a JUnit5 Extension where I have to take some action when a test method annotated with @Disabled is found. Unfortunately, beforeTestExecution() is not called for such methods. Does anybody have an idea how to intercept such @Disabled test methods ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

As described in the [User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-conditions-deactivation), you can disable the built-in `ExecutionCondition` that handles `@Disabled` by default by setting `junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate` to `org.junit.*DisabledCondition` (see [Configuration Parameters](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params) on how to set it). This will cause your tests to be executed.

Next, you need to implement your own `ExecutionCondition` extension, check for `@Disabled`, take your action and return `ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("...")`.

In order to avoid having to register your extension on each test class, you can activate [Automatic Extension Registration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-registration-automatic) and register your extension globally.

Depending on what you want to achieve, it may be easier to register your own `TestExecutionListener` (see [Plugging in Your Own Test Execution Listeners](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom)) and implement `executionSkipped()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! if I deactivate the @DisabledCondition, the test will be executed. I need to be informed that the test is Disabled (for reporting reasons) but the execution should be avoided. Do you have any clue how to do this ?

Comment: I've clarified my answer a bit. You need to register your own extension that implements the same behavior as the disabled default extension in addition to your custom action. However, if all you want to do is have reporting for skipped tests, you should really implement and register a `TestExecutionListener`.

Comment: how can I programmatically register a TestExecutionListener? I would like to pass some context information to the TestExecutionListener and the automatically registration does not allow passing any other information to the TestExecutionListener. The next question will be how to unregister the TestExecutionListeners ?

Comment: You cannot register the listener from the test class, you'd have to use the `Launcher` API directly (see the Javadoc for details).

Answer (score 0):

The extension point used here is https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-jupiter-api/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExecutionCondition.java

It might be interesting to find out how several implementors compose, i.e. if the 2nd one will be called at all and under what circumstances. You’ll probably have to dive into Jupiter code or do some experiments.